# SQLException too many clients vs. auth failed

Tags: postgresql, exception

I have a multi threaded app that connects to Postgresql. I want my app to try to connect again if there is too many clients, but I want to show error to the user is authentication is failed. Unfortunately, both these events throw SQLException and the only way to differentiate between them seem to be parsing text from toString() method. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has [error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

Are you absolutely sure they're not exposed in some way by the exception?

Plus, which language are you using? Java? If so, even though I don't have anything to do with Java, I think PSQLException [does expose that information](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html).

Comment: Thanks, this will get me where I want.

Comment: This is a bit funny. getErrorCode() returns private field vendorCode. This is set in contructor "public SQLException(String reason, String sqlState, int vendorCode, Throwable cause)". However, PSQException doesn't override this contructor and all implemented contructors assign 0 to vendorCode.

Comment: Funny, but what about [getServerErrorMessage()](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html#getServerErrorMessage()) then? Does it expose anything useful?

Comment: Still, I would need to parse the string (no useful ints there).